# Why the project file getting bigger and bigger

Tags: blend-files

I have already tried to purge and clean. but the file still contains a lot of textures that belong to no meshes and there's no way to sort all those files at once but to delete them one by one. and you can append all kinds of stuff into a new project and the new .blend file shrinks dramatically, which means there were tons of unused files in the old one.
But I can't use this method because I can only append files but I can't transfer all those settings in the addon.
Does anyone have solutions?